# Finitely generated group which is not finitely presented

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Is there any easy group theoretical way of showing that the wreath product $G$ of two infinite cyclic groups is not finitely presented?

I was looking for a finitely presented group with a central subgroup isomorphic to the free group of countable rank and whose factor group is isomorphic to $G$; in this way assuming that $G$ is finitely presented we get a contradiction.

Any ideas?